# Issue with temp table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

We are using Db visualizer Pro 12 edition to work on the Oracle DB.
Table structure with data as follows

```
 TableA
 
 Id   batchId  requestId Filename
 100  Btch100   Rqt1     ABc.zip
 101  Btch100   Null     Abc213.txt
 102  Btch100   Null     Abc5673.pdf
 103  Btch100   Null     Afdc213.txt
 104  Btch101   Rqt2     Abc213.txt
 105  Btch101   Null     Bbc213.txt
 106  Btch102   Null     zbc213.txt
 107  Btch102   Rqt3     z6gt213.txt
```

I need to update the requestid in the table matching with the same batch id

```
  Id   batchId  requestId Filename
 100  Btch100   Rqt1     ABc.zip
 101  Btch100   Rqt1     Abc213.txt
 102  Btch100   Rqt1     Abc5673.pdf
 103  Btch100   Rqt1     Afdc213.txt
 104  Btch101   Rqt2     Abc213.txt
 105  Btch101   Rqt2     Bbc213.txt
 106  Btch102   Rqt3     zbc213.txt
 107  Btch102   Rqt3     z6gt213.txt
```

I tried with creating private temp table and selecting rows based on request id and batch id and trying to update while keeping in while loop.

```
CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable AS
SELECT requestId,batchId FROM TableA WHERE requestid is not null  group by requestId,batchId .
```

i am getting an issue while creating temp table and inserting table data

```
Error : Unknown objectType 'Private' key word used in Create,Drop,or Alter statement.
```

Please suggest if there is any alternate way to update table with out using temptable

Comment: What Oracle version? If I remember correctly, private temporary tables were introduced in Oracle 18c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `MAX` or `MIN`. (The maximum or minimum of 'Rqt1', null, null, null is 'Rqt1'.)

If you want to update the rows in the table, then just use a simple `UPDATE`:

```
update tablea
set requestid = (select max(a.requestid) from tablea a where a.id = tablea.id)
where requestid is null;
```

If you only want to select the data, use `MAX OVER`:

```
select
  id,
  batch_id,
  max(requestid) over (partition by batch_id) as requestid,
  filename
from tablea
order by id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Tip: Make it easy for people to answer by using SQL, eg

```
create table t ( id int, batchid varchar2(10), requestid varchar2(10), filename varchar2(20));
INSERT INTO t (Id, batchId, requestId, Filename) VALUES (100, 'Btch100', 'Rqt1', 'ABc.zip');
INSERT INTO t (Id, batchId, requestId, Filename) VALUES (101, 'Btch100', Null, 'Abc213.txt');
INSERT INTO t (Id, batchId, requestId, Filename) VALUES (102, 'Btch100', Null, 'Abc5673.pdf');
INSERT INTO t (Id, batchId, requestId, Filename) VALUES (103, 'Btch100', Null, 'Afdc213.txt');
INSERT INTO t (Id, batchId, requestId, Filename) VALUES (104, 'Btch101', 'Rqt2', 'Abc213.txt');
INSERT INTO t (Id, batchId, requestId, Filename) VALUES (105, 'Btch101', Null, 'Bbc213.txt');
INSERT INTO t (Id, batchId, requestId, Filename) VALUES (106, 'Btch102', Null, 'zbc213.txt');
INSERT INTO t (Id, batchId, requestId, Filename) VALUES (107, 'Btch102', 'Rqt3', 'z6gt213.txt');
```

Now we can use a LAG to cascade the data down

```
SQL> select Id, batchId, requestId, Filename, nvl(lag(requestid ignore nulls) over ( order by id ),requestid) as x
  2  from t;

        ID BATCHID    REQUESTID  FILENAME             X
---------- ---------- ---------- -------------------- ----------
       100 Btch100    Rqt1       ABc.zip              Rqt1
       101 Btch100               Abc213.txt           Rqt1
       102 Btch100               Abc5673.pdf          Rqt1
       103 Btch100               Afdc213.txt          Rqt1
       104 Btch101    Rqt2       Abc213.txt           Rqt1
       105 Btch101               Bbc213.txt           Rqt2
       106 Btch102               zbc213.txt           Rqt2
       107 Btch102    Rqt3       z6gt213.txt          Rqt2

8 rows selected.
```

And then merge the results back in

```
SQL> merge into t
  2  using (
  3    select Id, batchId, requestId, Filename, nvl(lag(requestid ignore nulls) over ( order by id ),requestid) as x
  4    from t ) m
  5  on ( t.id = m.id)
  6  when matched
  7  then update set t.requestid = m.x
  8  where t.requestid is null;

5 rows merged.

SQL>
SQL> select * from t;

        ID BATCHID    REQUESTID  FILENAME
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
       100 Btch100    Rqt1       ABc.zip
       101 Btch100    Rqt1       Abc213.txt
       102 Btch100    Rqt1       Abc5673.pdf
       103 Btch100    Rqt1       Afdc213.txt
       104 Btch101    Rqt2       Abc213.txt
       105 Btch101    Rqt2       Bbc213.txt
       106 Btch102    Rqt2       zbc213.txt
       107 Btch102    Rqt3       z6gt213.txt

8 rows selected.
```

Comment: @Co Connor McDonald I am using Db visualizer and it s giving me error as  nvl is not command. Please suggest if there is any alternate way in DbVisualizer

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is to use [MODEL clause](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm):

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl (ID, BATCHID, REQUESTID, FILENAME) AS
        (   Select 100, 'Btch100', 'Rqt1', 'ABc.zip' From Dual Union All
            Select 101, 'Btch100', Null, 'Abc213.txt' From Dual Union All
            Select 102, 'Btch100', Null, 'Abc5673.pdf' From Dual Union All
            Select 103, 'Btch100', Null, 'Afdc213.txt' From Dual Union All
            Select 104, 'Btch101', 'Rqt2', 'Abc213.txt' From Dual Union All
            Select 105, 'Btch101', Null, 'Bbc213.txt' From Dual Union All
            Select 106, 'Btch102', Null, 'zbc213.txt' From Dual Union All
            Select 107, 'Btch102', 'Rqt3', 'z6gt213.txt' From Dual 
        )
```

... here is the code

```sql
--  M a i n   S Q L :
Select * From tbl
MODEL   Dimension By ( ID, BATCHID )  Measures ( REQUESTID, FILENAME )
RULES   ( REQUESTID[ANY, ANY] = Max(REQUESTID)[ID > 0, BATCHID = CV()] )
```

... ...

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
        ID BATCHID REQUESTID FILENAME   
---------- ------- --------- -----------
       100 Btch100 Rqt1      ABc.zip    
       101 Btch100 Rqt1      Abc213.txt 
       102 Btch100 Rqt1      Abc5673.pdf
       103 Btch100 Rqt1      Afdc213.txt
       104 Btch101 Rqt2      Abc213.txt 
       105 Btch101 Rqt2      Bbc213.txt 
       106 Btch102 Rqt3      zbc213.txt 
       107 Btch102 Rqt3      z6gt213.txt    */
```

The code above could be merged to do the update:

```sql
MERGE INTO tbl t
USING ( Select * From tbl
        MODEL   Dimension By ( ID, BATCHID )  Measures ( REQUESTID, FILENAME )
        RULES   ( REQUESTID[ANY, ANY] = Max(REQUESTID)[ID > 0, BATCHID = CV()] )
      ) x ON(x.ID = t.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    Update SET t.REQUESTID = x.REQUESTID
WHERE t.REQUESTID Is Null
```